# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm new to Flutter and I'm just trying to set it up for the first time. I've been trying to run the Demo App that comes with every new project, but Android Studio returns this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom'.
               > dl.google.com
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom'.
               > storage.googleapis.com
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom'.
               > storage.googleapis.com
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.5.0-5435860.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.5.0-5435860/aapt2-3.5.0-5435860.pom'.
               > storage.googleapis.com

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12m 38s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I've tried installing Gradle manually (offline) and while being connected to the internet. But it doesn't seem to download the .pom files it needs. I've even tried downloading the .pom files manually, in hopes of finding how to put them in the Flutter project manually, but the links (which I copied from the console) take me to "Error 404" pages.

[image: A screenshot of one of the pages]

Here's my `flutter doctor` result:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.476], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.49.3)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I don't have proxy settings enabled. I've tried to find a fix to the issue, but didn't find answers anywhere.

Comment: what is inside your `gradle.properties`

Comment: Maybe using a vpn can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem too. And all I did was to connect my computer and device to the internet and the issue was resolved. I hope this works..